# Integrate power apps to dynamically create epics in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powerapps

I want to create an epic dynamically in devops board using powerapps.Any leads please?

Answer (score 0):

That's possible. If you add the Azure Devops connector to your data sources inside of your app you can just use:

```
AzureDevOps.CreateWorkItem(
"YourProjectHere",
"Epic",
"YourOrganization",
"Title of your EPIC",
{
    description: "Your description",
    area: "YourArea"
})
```

This will create an Epic on your organization with your specified values.
You can also just create a Personal Access Token (PAT), which will allow you to do an HTTP request through power automate to add items to your backlog via an HTTPS call